# Extract text between parentheses with suffix

Tags: r, regex

Here is the exmple
`t <- 'Hui Wan (Shanghai Maritime University); Mingqiang Xu (Shanghai Chart Center, Donghai Navigation Safety Administration of MOT)*; Yingjie Xiao ( Shanghai Maritime University)'`
I want the output is the information in '()*'
In this exmple is
`Shanghai Chart Center, Donghai Navigation Safety Administration of MOT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to use the non-greedy wildcard `.*?`, otherwise everything between the first `(` and the last `)` would be caught:

```r
library(stringr)
t <- 'Hui Wan (Shanghai Maritime University); Mingqiang Xu (Shanghai Chart Center, Donghai Navigation Safety Administration of MOT)*; Yingjie Xiao ( Shanghai Maritime University)'
str_extract_all(t, "(\\(.*?\\)\\*?)")[[1]] %>% str_subset("\\*$")
#> [1] "(Shanghai Chart Center, Donghai Navigation Safety Administration of MOT)*"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

You can use the `rev()` function if you want to reverse the order and get it right to left.

This is far less elegant than I would like it but unexpectedly `"(\\(.*?\\)\\*)"` is not non-greedy, so I had to detect it at the end of the string. You can add  `%>% str_remove_all("\\*$")` if you want to discard the star in the end string.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.I want to extract the characters in '() *'Do you know how to do that

Comment: @XinDou oh with the star? This is unexpectedly more difficult, I'll try.

Comment: @XinDou I corrected my answer. This is not perfect but it works.

Answer (score 2):

To match only the contents of `(…)*`, the tricky part is to avoid matching two unrelated parenthetical groups (i.e. something like `(…) … (…)*`). The easiest way to accomplish this is to disallow closing parentheses inside the match:

```
stringr::str_match_all(t, r'{\(([^)]*)\)\*}')
```

Do note that this will fail for nested parentheses (`( … ( … ) …)*`). Regular expressions are fundamentally unsuited to parse nested content so if you require handling such a case, regular expressions are not the appropriate tool; you’ll need to use a [context-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) parser (which is a lot more complicated).

Answer (score 0):

Define a pattern that starts with `(`, is followed by any characters except `(`or `)`(expressed as a negative character class `[^)(]+`) and closed by `)*`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(t, "\\([^)(]+\\)\\*")
[[1]]
[1] "(Shanghai Chart Center, Donghai Navigation Safety Administration of MOT)*"
```

You can get rid of the list structure with `unlist()`